# How do I send a string containing special characters (",{,},: ) as an argument to python file from a make file?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, makefile, parameter-passing

I am trying to write a makefile from where I call a python script.
While calling the python script I send a string which would be converted to dictionary in python defined as follows :

```
DATE:= 25
YEAR := 2021
COMMA := ,
BRACE_OPEN := {
BRACE_CLOSE := } 
STRING_DICTIONARY:=$(BRACE_OPEN)\"Jan\":$(DATE)$(YEAR)$(COMMA)\"Feb\":$(DATE)$(YEAR)$(COMMA)\"Mar\":$(DATE)$(YEAR)$(COMMA)\"Apr\":$(DATE)$(YEAR)$(BRACE_CLOSE)
```

When I call the python script from makefile as :

```
`myscript.py $(DICTIONARY)`
```

The python only accepts **"Jan":252021** and omits the rest of the elements

I want the string argument as **"Jan":252021,"Feb":252021,"Mar":252021,"Apr":252021**

Make prints the following

```
{\"Jan"\:252021,\"Feb"\:252021,\"Mar"\:252021,\"Apr"\:252021}
```

But python receives the following :

```
"Jan":252021
```

I want python to receive this :

```
{"Jan":252021,"Feb":252021,"Mar":252021,"Apr":252021}
```

I need this and the convert it to dictionary with

**submission_date = eval(sys.argv[1])** in my script

it throws the error      SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can somebody tell me how can I resolve this?

Comment: I suggest you send it as JSON. You can use `jq` from the shell to create properly formatted JSON.

Comment: If you show an actual reproducible example of a makefile recipe, then show what make prints out when it runs that recipe and what the result is, we might be bale to help.  Also what do you mean by "it only accepts"?  You mean that if you look at `argv[1]` it has only that single value?  Or something else?

Comment: I have tried to refactor the question a little bit more, hope this makes it more clear

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I want to note is that you have some syntax/formatting issues with this line:

```
STRING_DICTIONARY:=$(BRACE_OPEN)\"Jan\":$(DATE)$(YEAR)$(COMMA)\"Feb\":$(DATE)$(YEAR)$(COMMA)\"Mar\":$(DATE)$(YEAR)$(COMMA)\\"Apr\":$(DATE)$(YEAR)$(BRACE_CLOSE)
```

Notice how the formatting of April looks different than the rest of the months.

Further, you may want to use a more "natively-supported" way to create your data dictionary. I am not sure what shell syntax you are using for your makefile because you did not specify, but if you are using Bash syntax for your makefile you can use an Associative Array to make this task easier. These are similar to dictionaries and are explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).

I presume there are similar types for non-Bash syntax makefiles.

Comment: Yes, I am using Bash syntax. I understood your suggestion, but can I send this to python as an argument from the make file?